# How to group code analysis results by cause/issue in vs2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

How do I group code analysis results by cause/issue in vs2012, or is this feature not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is not supported in Visual Studio 2012. This feature was introduced in Visual Studio 2013. ([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/03/what-is-new-in-code-analysis-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx))